# Change colour shapefile based on its own field in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have Google Earth Engine scripts with shapefile with 4 different colour code in each record.

[image]

The Symbology Colour should be display like picture above,
With "No" field in the shapefile as numeric code for different colour.

'No' = 1 = Blue (00aaff)

'No' = 2 = Red (ff0000)

'No' = 3 = Green (55ff00)

'No' = 4 = Yellow (ffff00)

```
var Shapefile = ee.FeatureCollection("users/k2yulianto/Shapefile/Symbology");

var empty = ee.Image().byte();

var palette = ['00aaff', 'ff0000', '55ff00', 'ffff00'];
// The shapefile Symbology's colour should be follow in it's own 'No" field record: 
// 'No' = 1 = Blue (00aaff)
// 'No' = 2 = Red (ff0000)
// 'No' = 3 = Green (55ff00)
// 'No' = 4 = Yellow (ffff00)

var filledAndOutlines = empty.paint(Shapefile, 'No').paint(Shapefile, 0, 2);

Map.addLayer(filledAndOutlines, {palette: ['000000'].concat(palette), max: 14}, 'SHP with edges and fills');

Map.addLayer(Shapefile, {}, 'default display');
Map.setCenter (101.4916, 0.4808, 10);
```

But My problem , the scripts just only show all become yellow.

Here is my GEE scripts

https://code.earthengine.google.com/028f6726a75ac54d92e28fc3daa8c47b

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a palette to display discrete/categorical values, the `min`-`max` range must cover exactly the number of items in the palette and match the desired range of the data. The number 14 is definitely not right, since your data ranges from 0 to 4. Also, you need to specify `min` as well as `max`.

If I modify your `Map.addLayer` as follows, it gives the result you want:

```js
Map.addLayer(
  filledAndOutlines,
  {
    palette: ['000000'].concat(palette),
    min: 0,
    max: palette.length
    
  },
  'SHP with edges and fills'
);
```

[image]

---

Another option that you *might* want to consider, instead of using `ee.Image.paint` and a palette, would be to use `ee.FeatureCollection.style`, which directly generates an RGB image with arbitrary fill and stroke colors — you would use `ee.FeatureCollection.map(...).paint(...)` to add custom style properties to each feature, and leave the layer visualization options blank. This is more flexible than `ee.Image.paint()` for visualization, but is less useful if you're intending to do any computation on the image between painting and displaying.